# Possible to force new growth in Monterey Cypress Tree?

Tags: trees

Poorly pruned cypress are abundant.  Is there any way to stimulate growth in the lower portions of an adult cypress?

Answer (score 2):

In bonsai, Monterey cypress are treated similarly to junipers. So, yes, you can grow new branches, but it is a many years long process and hit or miss about getting a bud where you want it.

Alternatively you/one could graft on a branch (or branches) just where you want it (or them). Even though this is faster than generating a branch from a bud, it is a several year long process - skill, some luck, and lots of patience are required.

Answer (score 2):

With evergreens, Yews and Hemlocks are fair/poor at generating new growth from old wood, and almost everything else doesn't (except in rare cases when the stars align).

On the bright side, Cypress often lose their lower branches for a variety of natural reasons, including lack of wind resistance or animal presence.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yAKS6b3.jpg]

Also, probably the most famous Monterey Cypress is "The Lone Cypress" in Monterey, CA [image: monterey cyrpress] also with no lower branches.

Perhaps you should allow it to generate some vegetation and see what you can work with. Here's an example of a top heavy Monterey Cypress bonsai that I think is stunning: 
[image: Monterey Cypress]